# Google Chatのタスク登録を自動化したい

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-workspace

Google Chatにあるタスク機能なのですが、どこかで登録した情報をシステムを通して自動で登録できる機能は作成可能でしょうか。

例)
Googleスプレッドシートで必要情報を入れた後、マクロボタンを押すと指定先のGoogleChatのタスクに登録できるなど

Answer (score -1):

[Google Tasks API](https://developers.google.com/tasks/reference/rest?hl=ja) が用意されているようです。
[Google App Script 向けのクイックスタート](https://developers.google.com/tasks/quickstart/apps-script?hl=ja) にまずは目を通してみてください。